# How to get month name in jasper studio expression editor

Tags: jasper-reports

I am using this command to get the date in jasperstudio expression editor

```
new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy").format($F{day_date})
```

This will return date value example like 01.01.2010 however i want the month to have a name like 01.Jan.2010 -- please advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your specified format "dd.MM.yyyy", MM gives you the month as a number.

You can use "dd.**MMM**.yyyy" to get an abbreviated month name.

Similarly, if you need the full month name you can use "dd.**MMMM**.yyyy"